# laravel vapor schedule job not running as scheduled

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I have setup a laravel vapor as per documentation. Everything is working fine except scheduler.

I have set few artisan commands at certain intervals. But commands are not running as per schedule. If i run command manually it works. Seems like artisan schedule:run is not running and hence commands are not fired on defined time.

I checked lamda cli logs, no errors found. What do i check?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue adding below line in vapor.yml

scheduler: true

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me but in my case it was solved by composer dump-autoload.